# Mail notification for SVN Conflict

Tags: svn, subversive

We are using Tortoise SVN and subversive plugin in eclipse for svn commit and want to notify through mail when there occurs any conflict at the time of SVN merge. How can this be achieved

Comment: Merge conflicts happen on the client only. Why do you need an email notification for something your users will see directly?

Comment: The concept is to notify the superiors regarding the conflict in code changes

Comment: Merge conflicts are normal and this sounds like an excessive level of micro management. This can only be achieved if you have total control of every client computer and can restrict users to only use tortoise svn. IOW, you can't do this reliably.